# Load More Data On Scroll With Vue And Vuex

Tags: vue.js, scroll, lazy-loading, vuex, loading

I would like to ask how can I display more data by using Vue and vuex. all data stored in vuex-store management already. From State management now I want to load more data on scrolling.
I found online solution by ajax. but I need to loading form state management (Vuex).

This is my Vue template:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name - Number of Products: <span style="color: red"> {{products}} </span></th>
                                <th width="100">&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody v-if="isLoaded">
                        <tr v-for="company, index in companies">
                            <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {  }
        },
        computed: {
          companies(){
           return this.$store.getters['exa1Company/getProducts'];
       },
       products(){
           return this.$store.getters['exa1Company/countProducts'];
       }
   },
   mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('exa1Company/indexResource');
}
}
</script>
```

My vuex store file is partial for simplicity

```
  export const getters = {
    countProducts(state) {
      return state.list.data.length;
    },
    getProducts(state) {
      return state.list.data;
    },
    getTodoById: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.list.data.find(tod => tod.id === id)
    }
  };

  export default {    
    namespaced: true,
    state: customerState,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work. use `companiesLoaded` in the template, and increase `page` when scrolled to bottom. I hope this helps.

```js
        data: function () {
            return { 
                page: 1,
                perPage: 20
            }
        },
        computed: {
          companies(){
           return this.$store.getters['exa1Company/getProducts'];
          },
          companiesLoaded(){
           return this.companies.slice(0, this.page * this.perPage)
          },
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your assist, also to be mention split replace by slice. I can not find idea how to page scroll @Jay Li